# A query, which contains rows position in another query (ranking)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I am building my ranking using query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY fame DESC;
```

I count position by incrementing a variable in rows loop

I want to add a ranking position to my profile sub-page, without fetching all the ranking first.

I thought of joining two queries, but I have no idea how to acheive this...

Comment: Not sure what this means "without fetching all the ranking first."
But you can use Rank() function instead of incrementing a variable

Comment: I think you should be using `SQL COUNT()` function and possibly look into `SQL RANK`. 
you should really get SQL to return the data you want to display first.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx

Comment: @SecretSquirrel: MySQL does not support window functions (`rank()`)

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT 
@rownr := @rownr + 1 AS row_number,
users.*
FROM users
JOIN    (SELECT @rownr := 0) r
ORDER BY fame DESC;
```

Comment: YEs you can, provided that the users table has a filed called row_number for instance.